# Shortest Perl solution for outputing 4 random words

Tags: perl

I have this one-line Unix shell script

> for i in 1 2 3 4; do sed "$(tr -dc '0-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 5 |
>   awk '$0>=35&&$0<=65570' | head -1)q;d" "$0"; done | perl -p00e
>   's/\n(?!\Z)/ /g'

The script has 65K words in it, one per line, from line 35 to 65570. The code and the data are in the same file.

This script outputs 4 space-separated random words from this list with a newline at the end. For example

```
first fourth third second
```

How can I make this one-liner much shorter with Perl, keeping the

```
tr -dc '0-9' < /dev/urandom
```

part?

Keeping it is important since it provides *Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Numbers* (CSPRNs) for all Unix OSs. Of course, if Perl can get numbers from `/dev/urandom` then the `tr` can be replaced with Perl too, but the numbers from `urandom` need to stay.

For convenience, I shared the base script with 65K words
[`65kwords.txt`](https://www.liveedu.tv/pastebin/KJ8T/raw)
or
[`65kwords.txt`](https://paste.ee/r/q0vug)

Please use **only core modules**. It would be used for generating "human memorable passwords".

Later, the (hashing) iteration count, where we would use this to store the passwords would be extremely high, so brute-force would be very slow, even with many many GPUs/FPGAs.

Comment: Does it have to be a shell script? Doing this completely in Perl is trivial.

Comment: Is your use case a password or passphrase generator? That's the major reason to want to use a CSPRN. 

Pruning back your 'one liner' when you've cryptographic integrity to consider seems a poor optimisation choice.

Comment: It can be in purely in Perl, yes, but acquiring CSPRN from /dev/urandom is mandatory!

Comment: It would be worth clarifying why it's "vital" - if you're doing password/passphrase generation, then that's significantly reducing the solution scope.

Comment: You appear to be asking for your work to be done for you for free. Such questions on Stack Overflow are frowned upon, to say the least: you are expected to be broadly skillful enough to write a solution yourself but it has so far eluded you. Do you know any Perl at all?

Comment: I don't think that my original oneliner can be shortened, but I am asking tha community, maybe someone knows it better, thats why the question.

Comment: I have trouble with the *Cryptographically Secure* part of your requirement. A selection of four words from a list is not a cryptogram, and the most ordinary random number generator wouldn't present a significant threat.

Comment: I'm not sure why 'short' is considered desirable here. Surely if you're worried about crypto-integrity, the key thing is 'provably correct/good' and length is almost entirely irrelevant?

Comment: I did find a better way by using `od`, which directly returns the right range of ints from `/dev/urandom` so not much of the rest is needed. It is also much shorter, but more imortantly it is much simpler. My answer's rewritten for this.

Answer (score 3):

You mention needing a CSPRN, which makes this a non trivial exercise - if you need cryptographic randomness, then using built in stuff (like `rand`) is not a good choice, as the implementation is highly variable across platforms.

But you've got [`Rand::Urandom`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Rand::Urandom) which looks like it does the trick:

> By default it uses the getentropy() (only available in > Linux 3.17) and falls back to /dev/arandom then /dev/urandom.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Rand::Urandom;

chomp ( my @words  = <DATA> ); 

print $words[rand @words], " " for 1..4;
print "\n";

__DATA__
yarn
yard
wound
worst
worry
work
word
wool
wolf
wish
wise
wipe
winter
wing
wind
wife
whole
wheat
water
watch
walk
wake
voice
```

Failing that though - you can just read bytes from `/dev/urandom` directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @number_of_words = 4;

chomp ( my @words  = <DATA> ); 

open ( my $urandom, '<:raw', '/dev/urandom' ) or die $!;
my $bytes;
read ( $urandom, $bytes, 2 * $number_of_words );  #2 bytes 0 - 65535

#for testing
#unpack 'n' is n  An unsigned short (16-bit)
# unpack 'n*' in a list context returns a list of these. 
foreach my $value ( unpack ( "n*", $bytes ) ) {
   print $value,"\n"; 
}

#actually print the words. 
#note - this assumes that you have the right number in your list. 
# you could add a % @words to the map, e.g. $words[$_ % @words]
#but that will mean wrapping occurs, and will alter the frequency distribution. 
#a more robust solution would be to fetch additional bytes if the 'slot' is 
#empty. 
print join " ", ( map { $words[$_] } unpack ( "n*", $bytes )),"\n";

__DATA__
yarn
yard
wound
worst
#etc.
```

Note - the above relies on the fact that your wordlist is the same size as two bytes (16 bits) - if this assumption *isn't* true, you'll need to deal with 'missed' words. A crude approach would be to take a modulo, but that would mean some wrapping and therefore not quite truly even distribution of word picks. Otherwise you can bit-mask and reroll, as indicated below:

On a related point though - have you considered *not* using a wordlist, and instead using consonant-vowel-consonant groupings?

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#uses /dev/urandom to fetch bytes.
#generates consonant-vowel-consonant groupings.
#each are 11.22 bits of entropy, meaning a 4-group is 45 bits. 
#( 20 * 6 * 20 = 2400, which is 11.22 bits of entropy log2 2400
#log2(2400 ^ 4) = 44.91
#but because it's generated 'true random' it's a know entropy string.

my $num    = 4;
my $format = "CVC";

my %letters = (
    V => [qw ( a e i o u y )],
    C => [ grep { not /[aeiouy]/ } "a" .. "z" ], );

my %bitmask_for;
foreach my $type ( keys %letters ) { 
   #find the next power of 2 for the number of 'letters' in the set.
   #So - for the '20' letter group, that's 31. (0x1F)
   #And for the 6 letter group that's 7.  (0x07)
   $bitmask_for{$type} =  ( 2 << log ( @{$letters{$type}} ) / log 2 ) - 1 ; 
}

open( my $urandom, '<:raw', '/dev/urandom' ) or die $!;

for ( 1 .. $num ) {
    for my $type ( split //, $format ) {
        my $value;
        while ( not defined $value or $value >= @{ $letters{$type} } ) {
            my $byte;
            read( $urandom, $byte, 1 );
            #byte is 0-255. Our key space is 20 or 6. 
            #So rather than modulo, which would lead to an uneven distribution,
            #we just bitmask and discard and 'too high'. 
            $value = (unpack "C", $byte ) & $bitmask_for{$type};
        }
        print $letters{$type}[$value];
    }
    print " ";
}
print "\n";
close($urandom);
```

This generates 3 character CVC symbols, with a known entropy level (11.22 per 'group') for making reasonably robust passwords. (45 bits as opposed to the 64 bits of your original, although obviously you can add extra 'groups' to gain 11.22 bits per time).

Answer (score 2):

## This answer is not cryptographically safe!

I would do this completely in Perl. No need for a one-liner. Just grab your word-list and put it into a Perl program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = qw(
first
second
third
fourth
);

print join( q{ }, map { $words[int rand @words] } 1 .. 4 ), "\n";
```

This grabs four random words from the list and outputs them.

`rand @words` evaluates `@words` in scalar context, which gives the number of elements, and creates a random floating point value between 0 and smaller than that number. `int` cuts off the decimals. This is used as the index to grab an element out of `@words`. We repeat this four times with the `map` statement, where the `1 .. 4` is the same as passing a list of `(1, 2, 3, 4)` into `map` as an argument. This argument is ignored, but instead our random word is picked. `map` returns a list, which we `join` on one space. Finally we print the resulting string, and a newline.

The word list is created with the quoted words `qw()` operator, which returns a list of quoted words. It's shorthand so you don't need to type all the quotes `'` and commas `,`.

If you'd want to have the word list at the bottom you could either put the `qw()` in a `sub` and call it at the top, or use a `__DATA__` section and read from it like a filehandle.

Comment: There's a caveat - `rand` is not the same grade of random as `/dev/random` - it's good enough for random words, but would be unwise for crypographic passphrases or passwords (which is one use case I can envisage).  So something like `Crypt::Random` might be a better way of generating random numbers.

Comment: @Sobrique I agree. But it's not a core module, and this sounds like core-only would be useful. Of course we could also just read from `/dev/random` ourselves. Is `/dev/random` different from `/dev/urandom`? In the question it's the latter.

Comment: Not much. `/dev/random` is a variant that will block if there's low entropy in the random pool. For most purposes this is a moot point. [/dev/random vs. /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)

Comment: Reading numbers from /dev/urandom is important, thank you!

Comment: It would be worth clarifying why in your question. If this is a passphrase or password generator, that's a specific use case that restricts the solution space significantly. `/dev/urandom` is a moot point if "all" you want is crypto-grade random.

Answer (score 1):

The particular method using `tr` and `fold` on `/dev/urandom` is a lot less efficient than it could be, so let's fix it up a little bit, while keeping the `/dev/urandom` part.

Assuming that available memory is enough to contain your script (including wordlist):

```
chomp(@words = <DATA>);
open urandom, "/dev/urandom" or die;
read urandom, $randbytes, 4 * 2 or die;
print join(" ", map $words[$_], unpack "S*", $randbytes), "\n";
__DATA__
word
list
goes
here
```

This goes for brevity and simplicity without outright obfuscation — of course you *could* make it shorter by removing whitespace and such, but there's no reason to. It's self-contained and will work with several decades of perls (yes, those bareword filehandles are deliberate :-P)

It still expects exactly 65536 entries in the wordlist, because that way we don't have to worry about introducing bias to the random number choice using a modulus operator. A slightly more ambitious approach might be to read 48 bytes from urandom for each word, turning it into a floating-point value between 0 and 1 (portable to *most* systems) and multiplying it by the size of the word list, allowing for a word list of any reasonable size.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of nonsense is talked about password strength, and I think you're overestimating the worth of several of your requirements here

- I don't understand your preoccupation with making your code *"much shorter with perl"*. (Why did you pick Perl?) Savings here can only really be useful to make the script quicker to read and compile, but they will be dwarfed by the half megabyte of data following the code which must also be read
- In this context, the usefulness to a hacker of a poor random number generator  depends on prior knowledge of the construction of the password together with the passwords that have been most recently generated. With a sample of only 65,000 words, even the worst random number generator will show insignificant correlation between successive passwords

  In general, a password is more secure if it is longer, regardless of its contents. Forming a long password out of a sequence of English words is purely a way of making the sequence more memorable
- *"Of course later, the (hashing) iteration count ... would be extreme high, so brute-force [hacking?] would be very slow"*

  This doesn't follow at all. Cracking algorithms won't try to guess the four words you've chosen: they will see only a thirty-character (or so) string consisting only of lower-case letters and spaces, and whose origin is insignificant. It will be no more or less crackable than any other password of the same length with the same character set

I suggest that you should rethink your requirements and so make things easier for yourself. I don't find it hard to think of four English words, and don't need a program to do it for me. *Hint:* **pilchard** *is a good one: they never guess that!*

If you still insist, then I would write something like this in Perl. I've used only the first 18 lines of your data for

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @s = map /\S+/g, ( shuffle( <DATA> ) )[ 0 .. 3 ];
print "@s\n";

__DATA__
yarn
yard
wound
worst
worry
work
word
wool
wolf
wish
wise
wipe
winter
wing
wind
wife
whole
wheat
```

#### output

```
wind wise winter yarn
```

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with you on a couple of points - origin is extremely significant. It's easy enough to make a password that 'looks good' and ticks all the boxes in terms of keyspace, but is actually deeply awful. `P4ssw0rd!` is not a strong password, despite being mixed case, symbols and numbers. And dictionary based attacks know this. By the book - `P4ssw0rd!` is 6.5 bits per character, for 58 bits... but it's clearly not that good.

Comment: Dictionary attacks know this though - so it's very common to use transformation rules to reduce a 2^N type brute force approach to something considerably simpler. 1/65536 x 4 gives us a 16 bit symbol, and 4 of them. So 64 bits of entropy _even if_ you have perfect knowledge of the algorithm. Assuming you have decent input RNG of course.

Comment: ... and that's a problem, because historically `rand()` has been very variable. For a while, the Windows implementation was 15 bits and time seeded, making it horribly easy to attack, simply because with a reasonable knowledge of generation time (and with password expiry, that's easy) you could simply guess them all. Known symbol space, generated from crypto-grade source gives more solid passwords than almost any 'user-pick' option, because for every 'good' password chooser, there's plenty who'll reuse or comply with the minimum based on the rules.

Comment: (oops, sorry, that's a bit wordy. And maybe I've misunderstood - if so, apologies)

Comment: I don't understand your notation *1/65536 x 4 gives us a 16 bit symbol, and 4 of them*. But I agree with the 64 bit conclusion, and I guess I think that 64 bits isn't great. Even `P4ssw0rd!` is unsafe only because it's common and obvious, which is nothing to do with the OP's *"many many GPUs/FPGAs"* which are irrelevant for dictionary attacks.

Comment: Well, that 65,536 is a 16 bit symbol, and you can just add the bits-per-symbol to get total password entropy. 64 bits _minimum_ entropy (one of the strengths of this technique - you can easily estimate the minimum entropy, where 'user pick' is highly variable) puts it a lot stronger than the very vast majority of passwords in use... :)

Comment: My point is that, to benefit from a rough random number algorithm, you also need its sources (i.e. the time of generation, as you said) and the *algorithm that uses that source*. In the extreme example of a fifteen-bit generator with a sixteen-bit symbol set, I'll agree -- something better is needed. But with that same symbol set `/dev/urandom` is no more "secure" than any half-decent 32-bit generator

Comment: *"for every 'good' password chooser, there's plenty who'll reuse or comply with the minimum based on the rules"* Yes, I guess there are people who will enter `a b c d` every time, and that easily pays for the use of an automated generator.

Comment: *"maybe I've misunderstood - if so, apologies"* You're experienced enough that you don't need to apologise. If there's any misunderstanding then it's as likely to be my choice of words that are at fault as your reading of them.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [Data::Random::rand_words()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Random#rand_words())

```
perl -MData::Random -E 'say join $/, Data::Random::rand_words(size => 4)'
```